# Match multiple occurences of string A in string B?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Is there a way to match multiple occurrences of string A in string B? `Match` only returns a boolean and `Pos` only returns the index of the first match it finds.

Maybe split the string into an iterable array based on a common delimiter and return a count somehow?

Comment: Could you break string A into smaller chunks and search each chunk?

Comment: hi @jesstme Thanks for chiming in. See solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is one way to solve it. It's not pretty but it works.

`=(Length([stringB]) - Length(Replace([stringB];"stringA";""))) / Length("stringA")`