# How to capture multiple occurences via Match?

Tags: business-objects

How can I make the 'match' variable count more than one?

Should I be using something other than match?

What I am trying to do is match up how many times a phrase appears in one column to specific people.

For example, the phrase might bike, but I need that to count every time either bike or motorbike appears.

I have tried:
`=count([Person number]) Where (Match([Transport];"*Bike*"))`
But that only shows 1 even where some people may have had it several times.

I tried:
`=count(Match([Transport];"*Bike*"))ForEach ([Event number])`
But that gave everything 1 for some reason and 2 where they had more, but didn't go above that

Finally:
`=count([Event number];All) Where ([Transport] = "Motorbike") Where (DatesBetween([Event date];CurrentDate();DayPeriod)<=1095)`
To just try and get the motorbike numbers, but I found more than what existed somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match multiple occurences of string A in string B in business objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300201/match-multiple-occurences-of-string-a-in-string-b-in-business-objects)